# Writing Snakes and Ladder program. having trouble moving the icons

Tags: java, javafx

i am writing a snakes and ladders program and i am having a lot of trouble getting the icons to move with the roll of the dice. I want to change the gridpane location each time the dice is rolled. Instead, the icons of the players just stay in the location everytime the dice is rolled. The code for the whole game isn't completely finished, but I cannot figure out how to move the

```
    public class SaltySnakes extends Application{
        ImageView Playericon = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Rainbow-Circle-3.png")));
        ImageView Playericon2 = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("BERNLORD.png")));
        Player player1 = new Player("Trump", 1, Playericon);
        Player player2 = new Player("Bernie" , 1 , Playericon2 );
        final Game RollGame = new Game();
        Board cell = new Board();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            launch(args);
        }



        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             primaryStage.setTitle("Salty Snakes");
             primaryStage.setResizable(false);
             BorderPane border = new BorderPane();

             HBox hbox = new HBox();
                    VBox vbox = new VBox();
                    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
                    vbox.setSpacing(8);
                    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
                    hbox.setSpacing(8);


                    final String cssDefault = "-fx-border-color: black;\n"
                            + "-fx-border-insets: 5;\n"
                            + "-fx-border-width: 3;\n"
                            ;

                    hbox.setStyle(cssDefault);
                    vbox.setStyle(cssDefault);

                   //ImageView iv = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("snakes-and-ladders.jpg")));
                     hbox.getChildren().add(addGridPane());









                    //vbox.getChildren().add(pane);
                    vbox.getChildren().add(addBerniePane(1,10,2,10));
                    border.setCenter(vbox);
                    border.setRight(hbox);
                   primaryStage.setScene(new Scene (border));
                    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Berniesnakers.png")));
                    primaryStage.show();


        }




        public GridPane addGridPane() {
              final String cssDefault = "-fx-border-color: green;\n"
                        + "-fx-border-insets: 5;\n"
                        + "-fx-border-width: 3;\n"
                        + "-fx-focus-color: transparent;"
                        + "-fx-border-style: dashed;\n"
                        + "-fx-focus-color: green"

                        ;


            final GridPane grid = new GridPane();

            grid.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(200)); // column 1 is 100 wide
             grid.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(181));
            grid.setHgap(1);
            grid.setVgap(1);
            grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            //grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);    //delete later************










            grid.add(Title, 0, 0);

            Text Players = new Text("Players: ");
            Players.setFont(Font.font("Arial" , 18));
            grid.add(Players, 0 , 35);

            Text RollDice = new Text("Roll Dice: ");
            RollDice.setFont(Font.font("Arial" , 35));
            grid.add(RollDice, 0 , 100);





            final TextField Player1name = new TextField();
            grid.add(Player1name,0,40);
            final TextField Player2name = new TextField();
            grid.add(Player2name,0,45);

             Button  Player1RolltheDice = new Button("Player One Roll!");
            grid.add(Player1RolltheDice, 0, 105);
            Player1RolltheDice.setStyle(cssDefault);
            Button Player2RolltheDice = new Button ("Player Two Roll!");
            Player2RolltheDice.setStyle(cssDefault);
            //grid.add(Player2RolltheDice, 0, 105);




                  Player1RolltheDice.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){ //add button
                public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                int DiceRoll = RollGame.RollDice();
                player1.addtocurrentScore(DiceRoll);
                int temp1=10;
                int temp2=1;
                int temp3=10;
                int temp4=2;
                for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
                    for (int j  = 0; j<10; j++){
                        if(cell.gameBoard[i][j].getCellNumber()==player1.getcurrentScore()){
                            temp1 = i;
                            temp2 = j+1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                addBerniePane(temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4);




                  ImageView DiceImage = RollGame.changeDice(DiceRoll); 
                    grid.add(DiceImage, 0, 110);
                }
            });










            Button Okayplayer1 = new Button("Okay");
            grid.add(Okayplayer1, 1, 40);
            RestartGame.setMaxWidth(180);
            RestartGame.setMaxHeight(100);
            RestartGame.setStyle(cssDefault);

            Button Okayplayer2 = new Button("Okay");
            grid.add(Okayplayer2, 1, 45);
            RestartGame.setMaxWidth(180);
            RestartGame.setMaxHeight(100);
            RestartGame.setStyle(cssDefault);


            return grid;
        }
        public GridPane addBerniePane(int First, int Pen, int Second, int Trator){

             GridPane pane = new GridPane();    


       pane.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
       int j=0;
       int f=0;
       int q=0;
       int x = 0;
       int z = 0;
       int r = 0;
       int h=0;
       int k =0;
       int l =0;
       int p= 0;

       for (int i =100; i>90; i-- ){
        ImageView KEK = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(Integer.toString(i)+".png")));
        j++;

        pane.add(KEK,j,0);

       }    
       for (int i= 81; i<91; i++){
        ImageView KEK = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(Integer.toString(i)+".png")));
        f++;
        pane.add(KEK, f,1);
       }
       for (int i= 80; i>70; i--){
        ImageView KEK = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(Integer.toString(i)+".png")));
        q++;
        pane.add(KEK, q,2);
       }
       for (int i= 61; i<71; i++){
        ImageView KEK = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(Integer.toString(i)+".png")));
        x++;
        pane.add(KEK, x,3);
       }
       for (int i= 60; i>50; i--){
        ImageView KEK = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(Integer.toString(i)+".png")));
        z++;
        pane.add(KEK, z,4);
       }
       for (int i= 41; i<51; i++){
        ImageView KEK = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(Integer.toString(i)+".png")));
        r++;
        pane.add(KEK, r,5);
       }
       for (int i= 40; i>30; i--){
        ImageView KEK = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(Integer.toString(i)+".png")));
        h++;
        pane.add(KEK, h,6);
       }
       for (int i= 21; i<31; i++){
        ImageView KEK = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(Integer.toString(i)+".png")));
        k++;
        pane.add(KEK, k,7);
       }
       for (int i= 20; i>10; i--){
        ImageView KEK = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(Integer.toString(i)+".png")));
        l++;
        pane.add(KEK, l,8);
       }
       for (int i= 1; i<11; i++){
        ImageView KEK = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(Integer.toString(i)+".png")));
        p++;
        pane.add(KEK, p,9);
       }
       ImageView Bern = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("BERNLORD.png")));
       pane.add(Bern, First, Pen);
       ImageView Trump = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Rainbow-Circle-3.png")));
       pane.add(Trump, Second, Trator);
       return pane;


        }

    }
```

Comment: Code is too much.. what's exactly the problem?

Comment: Yeah I figured. The problem is we figured we would reload the gridpane with each dice roll for the player. The diceroll would add to a player score which would then translate to their postition on the grid. The postition is sent to the gridpane method at the bottom to reload the gridpane but this time the player icons are placed to the appropriate postition, except the icons won't move at all when we roll the dice

Comment: I'm from phone.On every dice roll you have to clear GridPane and re-add the ImageView Objects in the appropriate positions(or implement an algorithm to find these positions and move the ImageViews).If you want to implement moving effects you need to look http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/jfxpub-animations.htm

Comment: We finally figured it out, your comment helped us revise over a part and we saw a way out. As Hulk Hogan would say, "Thanks BROTHER."

Comment: Thanks man!Nice to hear ..